# What format is the Safari History.db history_visits.visit_time in?

Tags: sqlite, safari, browser-history

When looking at the History.db from Safari, there's a table named `history_visits` which has a column named `visit_time`, which is a `REAL` value. It has values such as `470799793.096987`. What format is that in? I'd like to see it in a format such as 12/08/2015 05:12:05.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

***Update 2023-12-29:** With the following tool you can convert directly from Core Data timestamp to human date: https://www.epochconverter.com/coredata*

---

It's the number in seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001. It must be coming from an `NSDate`.

> NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date objects are immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001).
>
> — [NSDate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html)

To get a decent human value out of it, you must add `978307200` (the epoch for 2001-01-01 00:00:00).

This query should give you what you want:

```
.headers on

select datetime(v.visit_time + 978307200, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as date, v.visit_time + 978307200 as epoch, v.visit_time, i.domain_expansion, i.url
from history_items i left join history_visits v on i.id = v.history_item
order by i.id desc
limit 100;
```

Example output:

```
date|epoch|visit_time|domain_expansion|url
2015-12-31 11:51:27|1451562687.28465|473255487.284646|duckduckgo|https://duckduckgo.com/?q=current+timestamp+2015-12-31+11:51&t=osx
```

*PS: Just for future reference, the Safari db file is located at `~/Library/Safari/History.db`*

Comment: What exactly is `978307200`, the number of seconds?, what would 0 be in that space?

Comment: Just figured it out using this cool tool https://www.epochconverter.com, basically 0 is the Unix epoch, 0 seconds, and it maps to `January 1, 1970 12:00:00 AM`, and 1 maps to `January 1, 1970 12:00:01 AM`. In this coordinate space then 978307200 is the number of seconds that take you to the epoch date you give which is something Apple specific apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I found the domain_expansion field to be null in some cases, here's a modified query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(
SUBSTR(url, INSTR(url, '/')+2),
1,
INSTR(SUBSTR(url, INSTR(url, '/')+2),'/') - 1
) domain,
url,
datetime(hv.visit_time + 978307200, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') visit_time 
FROM history_items hi
JOIN history_visits hv on hi.id = hv.history_item;
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert the `visit_time` value in the *history.db* in an excel spread sheet, open the history.db file in a tool such as DB browser for SQLLite (Windows) and export the history_visits values to a CSV file.

Open the CSV file and create a column where you will populate your values in human readable time adjusted to your time zone, and use the following formula convert your NSDate:

```
=((((C2+978307200)/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)+(-5/24)
```

In the above formula, the time value is in cell `C2`, and my time zone `GMT-5`. To adjust to your own time zone adjust the statement in the last set of parenthesis. Presently I have `(-5/24)` to represent `GMT-5`.

When I first approached this conversion, I mistakenly assumed the time in the history.db to be epoch time, which starts at `1/1/1970`, and did not understand why there was such a skew in time. Adding the required conversion factor `+978307200` solved the problem.