# Why datetime(...) of a REAL date in SQLlite via JDBC returns inaccurate out-of-range results?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, jdbc, safari

I'm trying to read a `SQLlite` db on a Mac in Java 1.8 using `org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.14.2.1`. In particular, I'm trying to read dates, but I get weird results. Details follow.

Everything works fine except for a field of type `REAL` which represents a Date/Time. Notice that `SQLlite` doesn't have a specific type for dates, so they are stored either as

- a `String` (in a format like `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss` a.k.a. ISO-8601 strings),
- an `Integer` (i.e.: the number of seconds since EPOCH, or `1970-01-01
  00:00:00 UTC`)
- a `Real` (as Julian day numbers: time  passed since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. based on the proleptic Gregorian calendar).

Luckily, `SQLlite` provides functions like `date(...)` or `time(...)` to decode date fields. In my case, I used `datetime(...)` which converts a `Real` into a ISO-8601 string.

For instance, I converted the current time (actually `2016-10-26 18:37:24.073` and `2016-10-26 18:37:24.856`) to `Real` and back but I obtained the following values:

- `1362040-16036186-28 02:43:37`
- `1362040-16036186-29 17:38:02`

Notice that the *year* and *month* are totally wrong and only the *time* of the second value is correct.

I used the following code and the file that I'm reading is Safari's history (just visit any site on Safari, note down the system time and run the example code):

```
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        String filename = "/Users/stefano/Library/Safari/History.db";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + filename);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.setQueryTimeout(30);

        TreeSet<String> values = new TreeSet<>(reverseOrder());
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(
            "SELECT datetime(visit_time) AS value FROM history_visits;");
        while (results.next()) {
            String value = results.getString("value");
            values.add(value);
        }

        System.out.println(values.first());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The questions are: **Do you know why this happens? How can I get the expected timestamps?** Thanks in advance.

PS: Notice that I get the same numbers if I access the file with an application like `DB Browser for SQLite` so I think the problem is in the encoding itself... any idea?

Comment: If you use `ResultSet#getFloat` to return the numeric values from the table do they look like they are in the right ballpark, i.e., approximately 2.5E+6 for a reasonably current date?

Comment: You do not provide all the data. Edit your Question to provide exact values, showing your inputs, outputs, and expectations. Show your exact SQL performing the transformations.

Comment: @BasilBourque just added a MWE and instructions to run it, thanks!

Comment: @GordThompson I modified the MWE to collect `visit_times` as floats; the returned value is 4.99205952E8!!!

Comment: @GordThompson Maybe the difference from noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. based on the proleptic Gregorian calendar must be computed manually?

Comment: 499205952 is not a valid Julan day number. Where does this number come from?

Comment: @CL. it comes from `/Users/stefano/Library/Safari/History.db` (Safari's history on Mac). Specifically `SELECT datetime(visit_time) AS value FROM history_visits ORDER BY value DESC;` or `SELECT visit_time AS value FROM history_visits ORDER BY value DESC;`.

Comment: Maybe a problem of encoding? Big Endian/Little Endian? Really guessing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Safari apparently does not store the `visit_time` values in standard SQLite REAL datetime format. Instead, it stores the value in seconds relative to `2001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. For more details, see

[What format is the Safari History.db history_visits.visit_time in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34167003/2144390)